How to display all submenu items as a breadcrumb
I'm trying to display all submenus of the active page as a breadcrumb navigation on a section of the page. How could I go about this?
For example;
Home
Program
P1
P2
P3
About
When I navigate to the Program page, I want to display P1 - P2 - P3 as a sub navigation on the body section of the page.
Thanks in advance

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
